# TemplateUrl can't find my template

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

header-component

```
import { Component } from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: "header-component",
    templateUrl: "header-template.html"

})

export class HeaderComponent {

}
```

main-component

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

// Components
import { HeaderComponent } from "./header.component";
import {ParametersForm} from './form'

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  directives: [ParametersForm, HeaderComponent],
  template: `
    <header-component></header-component>
    <parameters-form></parameters-form>
  `
})

class MainApp {

}

bootstrap(MainApp)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

the problem is the header-template.html is not found

i tried the following

```
templateUrl: "header-template"
templateUrl: "header-template.html"
templateUrl: "./header-template.html"
```

yes template is in the same folder as rest of components which get imported correctly.

anyone knows the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> es template is in the same folder as rest of components which get imported correctly

## Fix

The `templateUrl` will actually be the url where the file can be located once the file is loaded by the browser. You are most likely getting a 404 in the browser. See the request made there and massage it to be where you expected the file to be.

## Better Fix

Use your loader to load the `.html` file as `text` content and pass that to `template` and don't bother with `templateUrl`

Comment: yep figured it out with first fix. for better fix, i do not know how do that really. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou as an example here is an html loader for system js : https://github.com/Hypercubed/systemjs-plugin-html/